# Interlaced Word Pairs

Tags: wordplay

There are pairs of words which can be interlaced or interleaved to form new words.

For example, PRIG and URN can be interlaced to form the word PURRING:

```
PRIG
URN

P   R   I   G
  U   R   N


P U R R I N G


PURRING
```

For another example, HAS and ERE can be interlaced to form the word HEARSE:

```
HAS
ERE


H   A   S
  E   R   E


H E A R S E


HEARSE
```

Notice that in the first example, URN fits snugly inside of PRIG, but in the second example HAS and ERE are shifted relative to each other.  It doesn't matter, as long as the letters are properly interlaced, meaning that each word in the pair contributes alternating letters to the combined word.

See if you can match each word in Column A with its partner in Column B and interlace them to form a new word.  The resulting combined words should be fairly common, or at least well-known, so if you find yourself chasing obscure words then you may be overthinking it.

Each item in Column A is used exactly once, and each item in Column B is used exactly once.

```
Column A                                        Column B
————————                                        ————————
AIL                                             AERIE
AIR                                             ALE
ALE                                             ALOE
BLOND                                           ALOE
BODE                                            AND
CAN                                             AND
CAR                                             ANY
CLIP                                            ARE
CLUE                                            ART
CREWS                                           ATE
CUE                                             COLD
CUSS                                            END
DAIS                                            ERA
ERE                                             ERE
FINS                                            EVE
FOE                                             FED
FUN                                             HIS
HAIR                                            HIS
HAS                                             HOES
HINT                                            HOT
HOE                                             IRE
JUT                                             IRE
LAND                                            LET
LUGS                                            LID
MOST                                            LORD
PECS                                            ODD
PIE                                             ODD
POLS                                            ODD
PROS                                            ODE
SAND                                            OLD
SET                                             OLD
SET                                             OLD
SHOE                                            OLD
SLID                                            ONE
SOLD                                            ONE
SUED                                            OPS
SUNS                                            ORE
TAGS                                            ORE
TERM                                            ORES
TIE                                             PAY
TOE                                             PIE
TOP                                             RED
TOPS                                            RUE
TRAY                                            RUE
VIE                                             TIE
VIE                                             WAS
WOE                                             WAY
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first step is to observe that there are only 2 5-letter words in the left column, which have to be paired with 4- or 5-letter ones in the right one. A short search yields

> BLOND + ALOE = BALLOONED
>  
>  CREWS + AERIE = CAREER-WISE

After that we're done with 5-letter words on both sides. The search on 3- and 4-letter words looks like it will easier to brute force:

> AIL + FED = AFIELD
>  
>  AIR + PAY = APIARY
>  
>  ALE + LID = ALLIED
>  
>  CAN + HIS = CHAINS
>  
>  CAR + HIS = CHAIRS
>  
>  CLIP + ALOE = CALLIOPE
>  
>  CLUE + OLD = COLLUDE
>  
>  CUE + OPS = COUPES
>  
>  CUSS + ORE = COURSES
>  
>  DAIS + IRE = DIARIES
>  
>  ERE + AND = EARNED
>  
>  FINS + RED = FRIENDS
>  
>  FOE + OLD = FOOLED
>  
>  FUN + LET = FLUENT
>  
>  HAIR + EVE = HEAVIER
>  
>  HAS + ORE = HOARSE
>  
>  HINT + ARE = HAIRNET
>  
>  HOE + ODD = HOODED
>  
>  JUT + ANY = JAUNTY
>  
>  LAND + ERE = LEARNED
>  
>  LUGS + ONE = LOUNGES
>  
>  PECS + IRE = PIERCES
>  
>  PIE + AND = PAINED
>  
>  POLS + ODE = POODLES
>  
>  PROS + ART = PARROTS
>  
>  SAND + TIE = STAINED
>  
>  SET + WAS = SWEATS
>  
>  SET + WAY = SWEATY
>  
>  SHOE + COLD = SCHOOLED
>  
>  SLID + ALE = SALLIED
>  
>  SOLD + PIE = SPOILED
>  
>  SUNS + ORES = SOURNESS
>  
>  TAGS + ERA = TEARGAS
>  
>  TERM + HOES = THEOREMS
>  
>  TIE + OLD = TOILED
>  
>  TOE + OLD = TOOLED
>  
>  TOP + RUE = TROUPE
>  
>  TOPS + RUE = TROUPES
>  
>  TRAY + HOT = THROATY
>  
>  VIE + END = VEINED
>  
>  VIE + ODD = VOIDED
>  
>  WOE + ODD = WOODED

After that there are only three pairs of words that my dictionary couldn't crack:

> BODE + LORD = BLOOD-RED
>  
>  MOST + ONE = MOON-SET
>  
>  SUED + ATE = SAUTEED

Comment: The last 3 look good, all are in Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a dictionary of American English that came pre-installed with my Ubuntu, it's sufficient for 90% of my puzzling needs and the rest I can usually figure out manually :-)